# Return Random Item from Observable Collection in C#

Tags: c#, random, observablecollection

I've got an ObservableCollection _filtered and I'm trying to select a random item from the collection and print it to a textblock tbkFeatured in Xaml.

```
    public void FeaturedMovie()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int index = rnd.Next(0, _filtered.Count); // Random range from 0 to length of collecton
        Movie value = _filtered[index];

        tbkFeatured.Text += Convert.ToString(value);

    }
```

I get an error 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll' on the

```
        Movie value = _filtered[index];
```

line.. just a little lost as to what's going wrong and down to correctly output the random item to TextBlock. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: if the length would be 10 and you get a random number from 0 to 10 you have 11 possible indizes, so maybe going with (_filtered.Count - 1) would do the trick ?

Comment: @MeAndSomeRandoms - The `Next(Int32, Int32)` method returns random integers that range from minValue to maxValue – 1. <br> So it will automatically take care of that.

Comment: @ Rahul Singh - You are absolutely right ! So this means the array _filtered might be too small. Can you show us the line you create _filtered ?

Comment: Are you sure that collection `_filtered` does not changing in another thread? After `int index = rnd.Next(0, _filtered.Count);`?

Comment: ObservableCollection<Movie> _filtered = new ObservableCollection<Movie>(); is how I  declared _filtered. The  Movie class contains a string Title, an Enum Genre and an int Rating.

Comment: 1st: a local variable init'ed to a new `Random` object is almost always the wrong way. Unless you are never going to pick a second random number, you should have a single `Random` object that is retained between each time the method is called (e.g. "private static readonly rnd = new Random();"). As for the exception, well...unless the collection count decreases between picking the random number and retrieving the item, it can't happen. So you must be removing an item or items from the collection concurrently with this code. Break in the debugger and look at `index` and `_filtered.Count`